# Is there any solution to these problems with Next.Js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, jsx

So i recently migrated from react to Next.Js, I am facing these issues and want to know if these have a solution :

1. Unlike react next can't just change a specific part of webpage and keep static part like navbar same throughout all my pages, I have to specifically add my Navbar component to all pages
2. The {styles.example} way of using css seems like a lot of work, I saw a lot of people using  to do css within the js file, but it becomes a mess when I try to make it responsive. Is there any way i can use css just as normal like import it in js file, and use classname='example' in example.module.css

Answer (score 3):

1. use _app

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

2. import css in _app is global

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support

---

css extended

- head(html way, won't apply loaders,make sure resource placed as refered): https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head
- import css (_app just like head but go webpack, named if not _app): https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support
- styled-jsx (inline,scoped by default, set global via prop): https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx
- element-style-prop: the react way

---

example cases

- head in _app: compiled global css like bootstrap reset...
- import css in _app: global custom css
- head in component: compiled css for component, like date picker
- import css in component: named fassion
- styled-jsx: css fassion, scoped by default, global if global prop set
- element-style: react fassion, element level

Comment: Still the style.css which will be globally added to _app.js will become a mess, and if i want separate css files for all pages then i will have to use fileName.module.css and it works differently

Comment: @Silenx I added more info about css in next.js, I believe head/styled-jsx/element-style-prop have covered most use cases, make an example if you still have problem